# How do I perform operations like read/write to a heavy file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, io

I am quite new to **node.js** and I want to perform operations(like read,write or store in DB) to large files(typically 5GB ~ 10GB).
What are the possible ways to do it fast and without affecting the main thread(UI).Do I need to implement multithreading?

I think since I/O operations are asynchronous,it will never affect the main thread. And I had tried to read a large file and write the contents to **response** object of **HTTP** like this -

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('largefile.txt',function(err,data){
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }
    http.createServer(function(request,response){
        response.writeHead(200,{
            "Content-Type" : "text/plain"
        });
        response.end(data);
    }).listen(8080);
    console.log("server started");
});
```

The size of **largefile.txt** here is **.25GB** only, and it has taken almost **5 minutes** for this program to run. Now in actual, I want the size to be (as I mentioned earlier) 5~10GB and type of file can be **.csv,.xls**. How should I do that, please tell the approach with examples(if possible).

Comment: Why would you even attempt to read an entire 5-10GB file into memory with one function call?  You may be causing disk swapping at the OS level.  Duh, that's going to take a little while.  You need a strategy for dealing with your data that is much more efficient than that.  What the best strategy is depends a lot on what the data is, how it's formatted on disk and what you're trying to do with it - none of which you've disclosed.

Comment: @jfriend00 As I had mentioned, I have not much knowledge of node.js . The ops that I want to do with the data are also mentioned above. Looking    for the best strategy with example, if you can help.

Comment: None of the particulars of dealing with data on disk have anything to do with node.js.  This is a generic programming problem for a large data set.  You will have to be a lot more specific about what the data is and what you're trying to do with it.  For example, if it's lines of CSV formatted info that you want to put in a database, then you should read one line at a time, parse it, write it to a database, get the next line and so on.  There are stream objects that handle data line by line for you.  There are databases that have an interface for storing data.

Comment: And, yes, if it's 10GB of data, reading a CSV file that large and writing every line to a database will take a significant amount of time in any programming environment.  If it's all async I/O, then your node server can interleave other operations, but it might be easier to just write a stand-alone node.js program that you can launch as a child process to consume your large data file and put it in the database.  That way you have multiple CPUs working and your main server thread will be less impacted.

Comment: @jfriend00 If i understand correctly, node.js is non-blocking, then what is the use of launching program as a child process or in different thread.

Comment: Node.js being non-blocking does not mean you're not hogging process time of your main thread. Node.js is single threaded, so async operations are thread-safe by default, because there is only one thread. However, every async operation running on that same thread still gets it's turn and allotted time to work in that turn, so a long running async operation will take away from other operations attempting to do their own work. Delegating a heavy job to a dedicated thread (another node.js process in this case) is the usual solution.

Comment: There's really still insufficient information in this question for a meaningful answer.  Selecting a strategy for reading a giant file and putting it into a database depends upon the type of data in the file, what you're doing to the data, the database being used, how often this needs to be done, how busy the rest of your server process is, etc...  Dealing with large data files in any language is a particular expertise which cannot be entirely explained in one answer here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from disk to working program memory is very slow. This is a hardware limitation.

If the file is CSV (Comma-separated values separated by newlines), you probably want to read it line by line, or search through for the right line and then read, instead of reading the whole thing into memory and then printing the whole thing out. If you read it line by line at least you're updating something as it's being read.

For a start, you can use [`fs.read`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) instead of `fs.readFile` to read the file character by character, looking for a newline character.

But a quick search for "nodejs read file line" shows there are many other ways to approach this with Node.

**Edit:**

I can't comment yet, but regarding child processes, as jfriend00 and SirDemon said, although NodeJS uses non-blocking IO (reading disk to memory doesn't block code) and it's generally event-oriented/asynchronous in design (execution may swap between sections of code while it's waiting on things) the code is only run single-threaded on a single CPU (code still blocks code). So a child process allows you to make use of another CPU. It was all designed for dynamic servers, so you could have code running and files being read almost all the time, but without the overhead of maintaining a new thread/process for each file read (which servers typically use thread pools for). (I think that's correct?)